# Ensure positive difference of two numbers

Tags: python

Looking for an elegant solution for the absolute difference?

```py
num1 = 6
num2 = 3
for i in range(num1+1 , num2):
    print(i, end=', ')
```

Thank you for providing valid answers and examples

Comment: Use the absolute value of the difference

Comment: Your question wording is not correlating very well with the application and code proposed. So what exactly you want - absolute difference, or an ascending range?

Comment: do your homework and provide us with a MCV example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 5):

You can actually use the built-in [absolute value](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#abs) function

```
abs(x-y) # will return x - y if x >= y, y - x otherwise
```

Another possibility is to use the built-in min and max functions:

```
for i in range(min(x, y), max(x, y) + 1):
    do_something()
```

Comment: You have edited your answer to be completely different after receiving 3 upvotes on the *old* version.

Comment: Sorry, I actually reread the question and realized that it was not what the OP was asking for. Editing right now.

Answer (score 3):

You could sort the numbers and unpack:

```
num1, num2 = sorted((num1, num2))
```

You could use a ternary operator:

```
num1, num2 = num1, num2 if num1 < num2 else num2, num1
```

But a simple `if` is less wasteful of cycles, if not screen space:

```
if num1 >= num2:
    num1, num2 = num2, num1
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be simpler to just put the two values in a list and sort it:

```
print(sorted([num1, num2]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `min` and `max`.

```
low = min(num1, num2)
high = max(num1, num2)

for i in range(low, high):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if num1 > num2:
    temp = num1
    num1 = num2
    num2 = temp

print(range(num1, num2))
```

Comment: Python's unpacking allows you to write that on one line without an explicit temp

Comment: You don't need a temporary variable to swap two values. Just use `num1, num2=num2, num1`

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the two numbers:

```
num1, num2 = sorted(int(input('Enter num%d: ' % i)) for i in range(1, 3))
```

Comment: Why not range(2)?

Comment: Because the sample code prompts for `num1` and `num2`, not `num0` and `num1`.

Comment: Nice. I didn't even notice that.

Answer (score 1):

abs() in Python

The abs() function is used to return the absolute value of a number.

Syntax:

```
abs(number)
```

number : Can be integer, a floating point

number or a complex number

The abs() takes only one argument, a number whose absolute value is to be returned. The argument can be an integer, a floating point number or a complex number.

If the argument is an integer or floating point number, abs() returns the absolute value in integer or float.
In case of complex number, abs() returns only the magnitude part and that can also be a floating point number.

```
result = abs(abs(num1)-abs(num2))
```